# PM2 automatically delete the process after 1month~

Tags: pm2

I am using pm2 to run my nodejs(express server) app. As i know pm2 will restart the app if the app crashed. But i don't know why the process is automatically deleted(dissapear) after i found out that the website is "503 error" and i try to type "pm2 monit" the process is dissapear.

Here are some info:

- the app is hosted on sharedhosting with ssh access.
- after installed pm2 globally, i start the app using the default command: "pm2 start [path_to_server_from_public_html].js"
- inside pm2.log:

```
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: --- New PM2 Daemon started ----------------------------------------------------
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: Time                 : Fri Aug 02 2019 11:05:35 GMT+0700 
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: PM2 version          : 3.5.1
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: Node.js version      : 12.6.0
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: Current arch         : x64
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: PM2 home             : /home/u1971755/.pm2
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: PM2 PID file         : /home/u1971755/.pm2/pm2.pid
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: RPC socket file      : /home/u1971755/.pm2/rpc.sock
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: BUS socket file      : /home/u1971755/.pm2/pub.sock
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: Application log path : /home/u1971755/.pm2/logs
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: Process dump file    : /home/u1971755/.pm2/dump.pm2
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: Concurrent actions   : 2
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-02T11:05:35: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-02T11:18:35: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGTERM]
2019-08-02T11:18:35: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-02T11:18:35: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-02T11:19:09: PM2 error: 1 : id unknown
2019-08-02T11:19:13: PM2 log: Stopping app:server id:0
2019-08-02T11:19:13: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-02T11:19:13: PM2 log: pid=31251 msg=process killed
2019-08-02T11:19:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-02T11:19:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-02T11:19:51: PM2 error: 1 : id unknown
2019-08-02T11:22:18: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGTERM]
2019-08-02T11:22:18: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-02T11:22:18: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-02T11:22:21: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGTERM]
2019-08-02T11:22:21: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-02T11:22:21: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-02T11:23:11: PM2 error: 1 : id unknown
2019-08-20T10:18:42: PM2 log: Stopping app:server id:0
2019-08-20T10:18:43: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-20T10:18:43: PM2 log: pid=5965 msg=process killed
2019-08-20T10:18:43: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-20T10:18:43: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:33:39: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGTERM]
2019-08-21T11:33:39: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:33:39: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:34:42: PM2 log: Stopping app:server id:0
2019-08-21T11:34:42: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:34:42: PM2 log: pid=9888 msg=process killed
2019-08-21T11:34:42: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:34:42: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:25: PM2 log: Stopping app:server id:0
2019-08-21T11:41:25: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:25: PM2 log: pid=15091 msg=process killed
2019-08-21T11:41:25: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:25: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:27: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:28: PM2 log: Script /home/u1971755/public_html/service/build/server/server.js had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
2019-08-21T11:41:43: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:43: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:43: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:43: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:43: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:46: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:46: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:46: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:46: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:46: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:41:46: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:41:46: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:41:46: PM2 log: Script /home/u1971755/public_html/service/build/server/server.js had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
2019-08-21T11:42:36: PM2 log: Stopping app:server id:0
2019-08-21T11:42:36: PM2 error: app=server id=0 does not have a pid
2019-08-21T11:43:36: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:43:36: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:43:55: PM2 log: Stopping app:server id:0
2019-08-21T11:43:55: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:43:55: PM2 log: pid=20025 msg=process killed
2019-08-21T11:43:55: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:43:55: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:45:02: PM2 log: Stopping app:server id:0
2019-08-21T11:45:02: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:45:02: PM2 log: pid=21490 msg=process killed
2019-08-21T11:45:02: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T11:45:02: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T11:47:54: PM2 log: Stopping app:server id:0
2019-08-21T11:47:54: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T11:47:54: PM2 log: pid=27614 msg=process killed
2019-08-21T12:08:06: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T12:08:06: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T12:12:23: PM2 log: Stopping app:server id:0
2019-08-21T12:12:23: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T12:12:23: PM2 log: pid=24151 msg=process killed
2019-08-21T12:38:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T12:38:26: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T12:39:41: PM2 log: Stopping app:server id:0
2019-08-21T12:39:41: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
2019-08-21T12:39:41: PM2 log: pid=10351 msg=process killed
2019-08-21T12:39:41: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T12:39:41: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T12:44:09: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGTERM]
2019-08-21T12:44:09: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T12:44:09: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-21T12:44:33: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGTERM]
2019-08-21T12:44:33: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-21T12:44:33: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: --- New PM2 Daemon started ----------------------------------------------------
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: Time                 : Sat Sep 14 2019 12:44:52 GMT+0700 
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: PM2 version          : 3.5.1
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: Node.js version      : 12.6.0
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: Current arch         : x64
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: PM2 home             : /home/u1971755/.pm2
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: PM2 PID file         : /home/u1971755/.pm2/pm2.pid
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: RPC socket file      : /home/u1971755/.pm2/rpc.sock
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: BUS socket file      : /home/u1971755/.pm2/pub.sock
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: Application log path : /home/u1971755/.pm2/logs
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: Process dump file    : /home/u1971755/.pm2/dump.pm2
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: Concurrent actions   : 2
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
2019-09-14T12:44:52: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
2019-09-14T12:46:02: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-09-14T12:46:02: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
```

NOTE:

- app first start date: (2019-08-02T11:05:35)
- last log before today(PM2 log: App [server:0] online)): (2019-08-21T12:44:33)
- app process suddenly dissapear date: (2019-09-14T12)

As you could see that the app or pm2 should work just fine right?. btw i just restarted the app manually today(2019-09-14T12:44:52) after i found out the app process no longer exist using: "pm2 start [path_to_server_from_public_html].js".

Please help me, it is so annoying if i need to restart the app manually after 1 month. Thank you very much guys...

Comment: did you restart your machine our cloud server?

Comment: no idea what you had edited. but I can help you with this.

Comment: @mehta-rohan i mean i restarted the app after found out that the website is no longer working. sorry for that. btw what should i do or do you have any idea?

Comment: my query: where do you deploy your server?

Comment: @mehta-rohan /home/u1971755/public_html/service/build/server/server.js, why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199455/discussion-between-mehta-rohan-and-json4live).